# Read.dta not working on Mac OS X

Tags: r, macos

A project that typically works on my Windows 7 office machine now gives errors on my Mac OS X laptop, trying to run it with R Studio. The part it fails is

```
library(foreign)
basis <- read.dta("myfile.dta")
Error in factor(rval[[v]], levels = tt[[ll[v]]], labels = names(tt[[ll[v]]])) : 
  invalid 'labels'; length 4 should be 1 or 3
```

`R` and `Rstudio` are on the newest version, I already ran `update.packages()`. As I'm a beginner on R itself, I'm completely clueless what to try next.

Could this somehow be related with OS X encoding? The stata file has German "umlaut" (that is, non ISO characters) in it.

Comment: what version was the stata file saved as?

Comment: Does your code contain library(foreign), which is required for the read.dta function? As @kolonel alluded to, [R does not read Stata files beyond Stata version 11](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/foreign/index.html). It may also help to check if you're running the latest version of RStudio, which is 0.98.1083 as of this writing.

Comment: Yes, library is included. It's not my .dta file, so I don't know which version it corresponds to (currently trying to find out how), but it worked under Windows. Hence I assume that's not the issue.

Comment: @FooBar did you try adding the option I indicated?

Comment: @kolonel yes, it changes the error (see update to question). Also, I saved the file as stata9 and I got the same error.

Comment: @FooBar sorry it didn't work, could you try the new answer and see what that gives you?

Comment: @kolonel that gives the same (new) error.

Comment: @FooBar okay, I will add one more thing in one second. Its a new approach.

Comment: @FooBar Please see the new answer and let me know if it helps.

Comment: @FooBar please don't forget to accept the answer which you found most helpful.

Answer (score 2):

Use package `memisc` instead. This is supposed to be more flexible. From the docs (found [here](http://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/memisc/memisc.pdf)) we have:

> The importer mechanism is more flexible and extensible than read.spss
>   and read.dta of package "foreign", as most of the parsing of the file
>   headers is done in R.

So back to the problem. First, load the following:

```
library(lattice)
library(MASS)
library(memisc)
```

and then use the call:

```
as.data.frame(as.data.set(Stata.file("filename.dta")))
```

Comment: This works. Its a bit annoying that I have to use additional packages now, but its surely better than nothing.

Comment: @FooBar This one is actually more robust.  I will add more details to my post.

Comment: @FooBar see my updated answer for a better explanation of what I mean.